# Twitter API update_profile_banner

Tags: api, twitter

Can anyone help with using the Twitter API to upload a profile banner using the account/update_profile_banner? I have been searching on Google for so long and can't find any solution, thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone give you useful help.  What language are you working in?  What code have you tried?  What isn't working?  What error messages are you receiving?

Comment: I have been mainly trying it via the Twitter API Console. I succeeded in doing it with update_profile_image but I can't get update_profile_banner right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://gist.github.com/hayesdavis/97756

It looks like the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_banner) are misleading, unless you are uploading a really small image, I expect it is critical to use multi part form data instead of encoding data in the query params.

Post your example code though, it's bad stackoverflow form to just say it doesn't work without showing the code and errors you are getting.